# Javac helloworld.java not working ( Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4)

Tags: java, linux, redhat, javac, yum

I have installed the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4.

After that I have installed the JDK by writing this command :

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

and then I wrote the command ( to check the installed version) :

```
java -version
```

it show me the installation version etc.

And the I wrote the below command :

```
javac helloworld.java
```

but it give me a message
"bash : javac : command not found"

What should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: `java` and `javac` come from different packages. What did the `yum` output?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul.
I think java and javac are in same package. (openjdk-devel)
yum output mean ? sorry did not get you.

Comment: Paul edited your question, I replied. Java comes from JRE, which is included in JDK. But if the install of JDK failed, you could still have java from an older install of JRE, but no javac.

Comment: Is the `$JAVA_HOME` empty (`echo $JAVA_HOME` should return nothing). What does `type -f java` show (should be /usr/bin/java, which is a symlink into /etc/alternatives). What does `type -f javac` show (/usr/bin/javac)? If the last one fails to return the expected value, check to see if there is a `/usr/bin/javac`. If there is not, then something went wrong with the installation (as @choroba suggested). Using `rpm -qa | grep java` should show the installed RPMs.